# Are the results of the system-check taken by "checkbox-gtk" public? Where can I watch them?

Tags: checkbox

With Ubuntu there comes a nice possibility to check the compatibility of a new (or even old) system and to send these data to the ubuntu developers. The tool to do this is "checkbox-gtk".

I would like to know, whether there is a chance to view these results because it would be nice to know if the future system will work with ubuntu.

Yes. I know about the certified hardware list, but there are only a few systems listed and i hope that more people test there systems with checkbox and commit the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Ubuntu Friendly](http://friendly.ubuntu.com/), the results are incorporated into that database.

Comment: perfect. thank you very much for the fast answer.

Comment: The link is dead...